# Edge & Json: copy a letter of a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, key, microsoft-edge

I've a problem only on edge when I get a Json from server. 
this is my json :

```
{"user":[{"pk":10,"user_group":[1,2,6],"uname":"5555678910","upass":"","first_name":"tutu","last_name":"","country":1,"other_countries":[],"brands":[]},{"pk":7,"user_group":[1,2],"uname":"aaa","upass":"","country":1,"other_countries":[5],"brands":[1]},{"pk":8,"user_group":[1],"uname":"222","upass":"","first_name":"","last_name":"","country":1,"other_countries":[],"brands":[]}]}
```

(you can copy/paste on : http://json.parser.online.fr/)

And only on Edge, I got this json :

```
{"user":[{"pk":10,"user_group":[1,2,6],"uname":"5555678910","upass":"","first_name":"tutu","last_name":"","country":1,"other_countries":[],"brands":[]},{"pk":7,"user_group":[1,2],"uname":"aaa","upass":"","country":1,"other_countries":[5],"braands":[1]},{"pk":8,"user_group":[1],"uname":"222","upass":"","first_name":"","last_name":"","country":1,"other_countries":[],"brands":[]}]}
```

The key "brands" give me "braands", when I change the key to "qwerty", i got "qweerty".

It's only on the second user, all the rest have the correct key.

Comment: I cant find any key `qwerty` and I get brands just fine

Comment: No, when i change the name of key "brands" to "qwerty", i got "qweerty"

Comment: When i use jsonCallback.user[j].brands.length, i've got an error like :
"Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" because the second object have :  jsonCallback.user[1].braands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, Edge work perfectly.
I've use hasOwnProperty to check if json have "brands" or "braands".